# Confused about prime number checking function

Tags: math

I came across a question on stack overflow about how to check if a number is prime. The answer was the code below. The function `int is_prime(int num)` returns 1 when the number is prime 0 is returned otherwise.

```
int is_prime(int num)
{
    if (num <= 1) return 0;
    if (num % 2 == 0 && num > 2) return 0;
    for(int i = 3; i < num / 2; i+= 2)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

All the logic in the `if` statements makes sense to me except for the for loop expressions. I don't get why the division `i < num / 2` happens and why `i+= 2` is being used. Sure one is there to advance the counter and the other is to halt the loop. but why half the number and why increment by two. Any reasonable explanation will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A number cannot have a divisor larger then its own half (think about it). And since 2 was already checked, and we start from 3, why go over all even numbers? The +2 increment simply skips 4, 6, 8 etc

Comment: All prime numbers except 2 are odd.  There's no need to test even divisors.  Using num/2 saves a lot of futile work; it would be better to use the square root of n as the bound.  No number bigger than n/2 is a factor of n.  Any number bigger than the square root of n that is a factor of n also has a cofactor that is smaller than the square root of n so there's no need to double check.

Comment: In fact, you don't even need to go all the way to `num/2` (for `num` > 4).  If `num` is composite then it has a divisor less than or equal to `sqrt(num)`.

Comment: That's a simple math question, not related to programming per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the loop's increment:
The second `if` (`if (num % 2 == 0)`) checks if the number is even, and terminates the function if it is. If the function isn't terminated, we know that it's odd, and thus, may only be divisible by other odd numbers. Hence, the loop starts at 3 and checks the number against a series of odd numbers - i.e., increments the potential divisor by 2 on each iteration.

Regarding the loop's stop condition:
The smallest integer larger than 1 is 2. Thus, the largest integer that could ever divide an integer n is n/2. Thus, the loop works it's way up to `num/2`. If it didn't find a divisor for `num` by the time it reaches `num/2`, it has no chance to ever find such a divisor, so it's pointless to keep on going.